# NodeJS capture output of shell exec to const

Tags: node.js

Im trying to capture the stdout of a shell exec and assign it to a constant for later retrieval.

```
//const { exec } = require("child_process");
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec)


async function shellexec2(command){
  const commandout = await exec(command)
  return { commandout }
};

var sentnlURL = "https://testapi.test.io/"
var origin = 'Origin: http://www.test.io'
var method = 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET'
var corscheck = "curl -I -X OPTIONS -H "+origin+" -H "+method+" "+sentnlURL+" 2>&1 | grep -i 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"
var t = shellexec2(corscheck)
console.log(t)
```

The only output I get is Promise <pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of `shellexec2` is a function marked with `async` it returns a promise, you need to unwrap it to get the value. i would write something like:

```
//const { exec } = require("child_process");
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec)


async function shellexec2(command){
  const commandout = await exec(command)
  return { commandout }
};

(async function main(){
var sentnlURL = "https://testapi.test.io/"
var origin = 'Origin: http://www.test.io'
var method = 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET'
var corscheck = "curl -I -X OPTIONS -H "+origin+" -H "+method+" "+sentnlURL+" 2>&1 | grep -i 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"
var t = await shellexec2(corscheck)
console.log(t)})();
```